# Is there an equivalent TO_CHAR or TO_DATE SQL function in HSQLDB, ver. 1.8.0?

Tags: sql, hsqldb, to-date, to-char

I have an HSQLDB, ver. 1.8.0, database that I would like to run some SQL date functions on (such as a date range select).

Is there an equivalent HSQL function to do this with a column that is defined as a BIGINT?

Comment: is google down?  this was returned on top:  http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html

Comment: All of those date functions listed on the link you provided all deal with DATETIME or TIMESTAMP formatted datatypes.  I'm looking for something that will handle a date that was stored as a BIGINT datatype.  
Unfortunately for me, this is a vendor provided schema that cannot be changed to a DATETIME type.